# Set lockscreen image for background audio

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I want to customize the lockscreen image for background audio playing. I have used [[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter] setNowPlayingInfo] but nothing have changed on the lockscreen. For clarification, the  audio playing is from the UIWebView (Youtube player API). Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Music apps can change the lock screen wallpaper because iOS automatically displays the album artwork for the song/podcast/etc that's playing (see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Chapters/Reference.html). As far as I know, it's not an API that's publicly available to developers. I'm pretty sure apple will reject if we modify the lock-Screen image.

Comment: It seems that the link is broken